# What's a jquery plugin for alternating images that comes with a number navigation menu?

Tags: jquery, plugins, slideshow

Basically I have a list of images that are to be displayed as a slide show.
I was looking for a plugin that has numbers that display each slide, and can also be used to navigate between them.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[Easy Slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider) is attractive and has options for numeric navigatioin.